# Spring Boot Mongo DB Inheritance

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
Class A{
public String phone;
}

@Document
Class B extends A{
public String location;
///getter and setter
}

@Repository
public interface B extends MongoRepository<B, String> {

   List<B> findByphone(String wphone);

}
```

When using this findByphone(phone) my api saying this

"status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No property 'phone' found on class com.example.demo.model.B! Did you mean: phone,Phone?"

Comment: Have you tried @MapperSuperClass annotation on class A?

Comment: You should Change `findByphone` to `findByPhone`. camel case Have been neglected.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@Field` in your mongodb fields and also you need to have an `@Id` associated with each of your document

```java
Class A {

    @Field
    public String phone;

    // getters and setters
}

@Document(collection = "B")
Class B extends A {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field
    public String location;

    // getter and setter
}
```

Also in your repository interface use the method like

```
 List<B> findByPhone(String wphone);
```